# How to have clickable background view, which won't cause clicking events on Views that are on top of it?

Tags: android, onclicklistener

This is a tiny question which for some reason I couldn't find here, and for some reason it's the first time I got an issue with.

### Background

I need to have some background View that is clickable, yet not have any other view that's on top of it to cause this clicking event.

### The problem

For this, I got this layout:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/backgroundView" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center" android:background="#f00" android:gravity="center" android:padding="100dp"
        android:text="Hello World!" android:textSize="50sp" />
</FrameLayout>
```

And I added this in code:

```
findViewById<View>(R.id.backgroundView).setOnClickListener {
    Log.d("AppLog", "CLICK " + System.currentTimeMillis())
}
```

This works, but it also gets triggered when I click on the other View (the large TextView).

### What I've tried

I tried this:

```
findViewById<View>(R.id.textView).setOnClickListener {  }
```

This works, but just as setting `clickable=true`, it also gives feedback (vibrate and/or sound) as if it indeed does something for clicking. Even the IDE warns that I should make it focusable .

I also tried various other attributes (including `android:hapticFeedbackEnabled="false"` to try to avoid clicking feedback), but none seems to fit this case.

Eventually, the only thing that did work and didn't cause any side-effects, is to use OnTouchListener instead:

```
//noinspection AndroidLintClickableViewAccessibility
findViewById<View>(R.id.textView).setOnTouchListener { _, _ -> true }
```

This works nicely, but I find it weird that I need to do it for every View that's on top of the background View...

### The question

Is this indeed the best option I should use?

Comment: I tried to set `clickable="true"`, I don't know why but there is no feedback sound from `TextView`, it works fine

Comment: @Ehsanmsz Try on emulator and you will hear the clicking sound. Maybe you have it disabled in the OS settings.

Comment: I tried on emulator (API 29 and 27) when I click the background view I hear click sound, no sound from `TextView`

Comment: May be, you can extend the Layouts (Frame/Relative/Linear etc) and do the setOnTouchListener() on all the children and use these custom layouts in your XMLs.

Comment: @RahulShukla That's more than the workaround that I've found. I asked about something more official/standard.

Comment: Then I believe you are doing this the standard way since the views are drawn in a stack and each one will respond to touch event, as you have observed yourself.
My comment was based on the assumption that you might be needing this "workaround" at multiple places, hence extending the layout seemed to be a better option.

Comment: @RahulShukla I see. This makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

This is because Child views are drawn in a stack with the most recently added child on top. FrameLayout works this way, so it should be used with caution.

Comment: So what are the alternative solutions?

Comment: Can you change the FrameLayout? Linear or Relative or Constraint

Comment: FrameLayout is the one used here. I tried RelativeLayout and ConstraintLayout, and both have this issue.